# Adding resistance/inertia/dead zone to scrolling in Android

Tags: android, scroll

I'm trying to implement a UI with a scrollable component that has a certain resistance to starting the scroll - ie. that you have to drag it a certain number of pixels before the scroll starts. Is this supported in Android, and if not is it something that can be added? The idea is to allow a scrolling component to snap to certain positions and resist being moved from them accidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to listen to [motion events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) and track what's happening yourself.